# How do I open inAppBrowser using Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inappbrowser

I am new to using Angular JS and have a question regarding the syntax. I am using Angular with Phonegap build and require an inAppBrowser. The inAppBrowser opens with the function window.open. I need to pass the url which is in {{info.link}} as shown below. I also need other parameters after the url.

```
    <div ng-repeat="info in rider">

     <ul data-role="listview"  data-inset="false" data-theme="a" >

         <li><a href'#' onclick=window.open('{{info.link}}' ,'_blank','location=yes,toolbar=yes,allowInlineMediaPlayback=yes')>{{info.name}}</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

I can not get the link to work and the javascript console just displays info.link. Is my syntax incorrect or is there another problem that I am missing? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: don't use `onclick` in angular...do it from controller or directive using ng-click.

Comment: Piggyback on @charlietfl's comment. See [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick). Also keep in mind that Cordova plugins (like inAppBrowser) can only be used after Cordova fires [`deviceready`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready). This isn't that big of a issue here, but you may want to setup your architecture to prevent early access to Cordova.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I setup the function in the controller using ng-click. Works perfect now.

Comment: were you able to get the value in info.link while running your app on the device?  I am having trouble with that.