# Ionic InAppBrowser - how to print a variable value in single quotes

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to  print the value of merchant.merchant_url for my inAppBroswer call.  I have looked at the recommended javascript to parse using the A tag at the blog by Nic. https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/12/open-dynamic-links-using-cordova-inappbrowser/

However, this impacts my other links on the app that I do not need to open in the InAppBrowser.  Can someone please recomend how can I print this url value?  I tried ng-href as well  but then the opened site takes over the app and there is no way to exit.

I have also tried using ng-click as suggested here [How do I open inAppBrowser using Angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497543/how-do-i-open-inappbrowser-using-angular-js)

But this doesn't help either.  I know for a fact that merchant.merchant_url has value because i can print it outside my a href.   However I having trouble getting it in single quotes for the execution.    I have tested non-dynamic links and they work fine in the app.  Stripped off < > for the so that the code is readable.

a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('{{merchant.merchant_url}}', '_blank', 'location=yes'); return false;"
               View
            /a

Comment: can you show the log or merchant.merchant_url

Comment: It is right now as simple as - http://www.somewebsitename.com

Answer (score 1):

Past this code  your controller:

```
$scope.urlOpen = function(url) {
    console.log(url);
    window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
};
```

and change in your view:

```
<a class="item" href="#" ng-click="urlOpen({{merchant.merchant_url}})">View </a>
```

Comment: Sorry doesn't work.  It doesn't even open the urlOpen function.

Comment: I made it work. you had single quotes missing.  Please see below.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the code posted by xuser is ok. Except that merchant.merchant_url has to be in single quotes.

urlOpen('{{merchant.merchant_url}}')